# Fill ArrayBuffer with pairs of Double

Tags: scala, arraybuffer

I need some guidance here, please.

What I have:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var buffer = ArrayBuffer.empty[(Double, Double)]
```

and I want to fill the buffer with pairs. 
I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
for(someCycle){
    buffer += (someDouble, someOtherDouble)
}
```

the error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: (Double, Double)
              buffer += (someDouble, otherDouble)
```

I understand the error but I can't figure out the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `+=` is a function, the compiler is inferring it as:

```
buffer.+=(someDouble, someOtherDouble)
```

Making it think you're trying to pass two arguments to `+=` instead of one (the error message is a bit misleading).

You need an additional parenthesis:

```
buffer += ((someDouble, someOtherDouble))
```

Or alternatively:

```
buffer += (someDouble -> someOtherDouble)
```